# How do I extract the ROM file from this DOS exe BIOS updater?

Tags: bios, dell-vostro

I am trying to update my DELL VOSTRO 260 BIOS. I am struggling to get anywhere, see for more info:

- [Cannot execute a DELL BIOS update for a VOSTRO 260 machine](https://superuser.com/questions/832822/cannot-execute-a-dell-bios-update-for-a-vostro-260-machine)

I decided to simply extract the flashrom directly. I am not trying to run the flashing step, simply to extract the ROM from the exe. So if I download the exe and try to run it using dosemu, here is what I get:

```
$ wget http://downloads.dell.com/FOLDER01639275M/1/MS-A10.exe
$ dosemu -dumb MS-A10.exe > log
$ cat log
SfxDos v2.11. [2012/06/25]
Extracting Files: [6174382 / 6174382] 100%  
Missing SMBIOS Table
```

What does this means ? Has anyone managed to extract the actual firmware from those exe ? I could not find anything working:

```
$ unrar l MS-A10.exe 

UNRAR 5.00 beta 8 freeware      Copyright (c) 1993-2013 Alexander Roshal

MS-A10.exe is not RAR archive
```

or

```
$ unzip -l MS-A10.exe 
Archive:  MS-A10.exe
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of MS-A10.exe or
        MS-A10.exe.zip, and cannot find MS-A10.exe.ZIP, period.
```

For reference:

```
$ file MS-A10.exe 
MS-A10.exe: MS-DOS executable
```

How do I extract the ROM file from this self extracting DOS exe ?

Comment: What does what mean?  You won't be able to extract a MS-DOS executable.  The errors are pretty clear what your working with isn't an archive.

Comment: Actually, it’s “PE32 executable (GUI) Intel 80386, for MS Windows”, by the way. ;) Also, the internet doesn’t know “SfxDos”, probably some DELL *homebrew* solution.

Comment: @daniel-b how did you see this is a PE32 exe (GUI) ?

Comment: That’s the output of both Cygwin’s and Gentoo’s `file` command. I guess your distribution’s magic files just aren’t that good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually that was trivial, simply run it under wine:

```
$ wine MS-A10.exe
```

The output will be found in .wine directory:

```
$ find $HOME/.wine | grep MS-A10
/home/mathieu/.wine/drive_c/users/mathieu/Temp/MS-A10
/home/mathieu/.wine/drive_c/users/mathieu/Temp/MS-A10/AFUWIN.EXE
/home/mathieu/.wine/drive_c/users/mathieu/Temp/MS-A10/AMIFLDRV.VXD
/home/mathieu/.wine/drive_c/users/mathieu/Temp/MS-A10/AMIFLDRV64.SYS
/home/mathieu/.wine/drive_c/users/mathieu/Temp/MS-A10/AMIFLDRV32.SYS
/home/mathieu/.wine/drive_c/users/mathieu/Temp/MS-A10/RosaBUU.exe
/home/mathieu/.wine/drive_c/users/mathieu/Temp/MS-A10/Pmxdll.dll
/home/mathieu/.wine/drive_c/users/mathieu/Temp/MS-A10/Idrvdll.dll
/home/mathieu/.wine/drive_c/users/mathieu/Temp/MS-A10/FWUpdLcl.exe
/home/mathieu/.wine/drive_c/users/mathieu/Temp/MS-A10/settings.ini
/home/mathieu/.wine/drive_c/users/mathieu/Temp/MS-A10/error.log
/home/mathieu/.wine/drive_c/users/mathieu/Temp/MS-A10/1176upd.BIN
/home/mathieu/.wine/drive_c/users/mathieu/Temp/MS-A10/AFUWINx64.EXE
/home/mathieu/.wine/drive_c/users/mathieu/Temp/MS-A10/RosaBUU.log
/home/mathieu/.wine/drive_c/users/mathieu/Temp/MS-A10/MS-A10.BIN
/home/mathieu/.wine/drive_c/users/mathieu/Temp/MS-A10/FWUpdLcl64.exe
```

with:

```
$ file MS-A10.BIN
MS-A10.BIN: Intel serial flash for PCH ROM
```

I guess this has little interest for anyone trying to do this BIOS update, you should be aware that using a Win7/32bits repair disk is not an option (I followed instructions from [here](http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/how-get-free-legal-copy-windows-7-installation-disk.htm)). Indeed the DLL needed at runtime requires that oledlg.dll be found:

```
$ objdump -x RosaBUU.exe  | grep DLL
 vma:            Hint    Time      Forward  DLL       First
    DLL Name: dbghelp.dll
    DLL Name: KERNEL32.dll
    DLL Name: USER32.dll
    DLL Name: GDI32.dll
    DLL Name: COMDLG32.dll
    DLL Name: WINSPOOL.DRV
    DLL Name: ADVAPI32.dll
    DLL Name: SHELL32.dll
    DLL Name: COMCTL32.dll
    DLL Name: SHLWAPI.dll
    DLL Name: oledlg.dll
    DLL Name: ole32.dll
    DLL Name: OLEAUT32.dll
```

Apparently this DLL is not present from a Win7/32bits repair disk.

Answer (score 1):

There is a command-line switch to extract the ROM (may require Windows):

```
MS-A10.exe /writeromfile
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the output when you run the EXE file with extra parameter "-?" ?
You might get a list of usable command-line options.

If it is made with an old version of RAR for DOS then usually "-x" would do an extract only, without trying to run the BIOS flasher immediately afterwards.

Anyway: 
You will never be able to run the DOS-based flash-utility from within a Linux environment. That is actually causing the SMBios message you are seeing. It means it can't locate the BIOS-chip. An emulator like dosemu won't help. It can't give the DOS command the necessary low-level access to the hardware.

The best option would appear be to create a USB boot-stick or Bootable CD with FreeDOS and run the EXE from that. That will not require unpacking the EXE at all.
(When running from read-only media you will have to setup FreeDOS to make a RAM-disk and run the EXE from there. It will need a writable working directory to extract the BIOS file to.)