# Cannot execute a DELL BIOS update for a VOSTRO 260 machine

Tags: bios, dell-vostro, freedos

I am trying to update my DELL VOSTRO 260 BIOS. I am struggling to get anywhere. If I download the exe and try to run it using a FreeDOS USB drive:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DellBIOS#Upgrading_with_a_FreeDOS_USB_drive

here is what I get:

```
C:\> ms-a10
SfxDos v2.11 [2012/06/25]
Extracting Files: [6174382 / 6174382] 100%

BIOS Version:
    Current Version: A04

    New Version:    :A10

Update BIOS (y/n)? y
Disable secure compatibility function.
CurVer:A04, Chk version A: A00, Chk version X :X00
-      Error: Problem allocating memory
Get ME Firmware version…Compare ME version…

The ME version is same or lower than current ME version. Skip update ME
```

Obviously something went wrong, but what ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program will not actually run in DOS (which explains your memory allocation error).
I've not tried this but theoretically you should be able to run this EXE from a Windows PE environment like the Win7 PE or BART's PE if you can get access to the files needed to build it or find a ready made ISO on the net.

> So far so good, but you will notice that the download is a Windows
>   executable. Just as this cannot be run under Ubuntu (or any other
>   Linux), it also will not run under legacy versions of Windows, in
>   particular MS-DOS or any emulation of MS-DOS. This is in spite of
>   anything it may say on the download page about being compatible with
>   earlier versions of Windows; using any legacy DOS-type environment the
>   .exe runs, but exits without doing anything except printing out an
>   annoying message.
>
> The key ingredient at this point is a Windows 7 Repair Disk. There are
>   several ways to obtain one, including buying one from sources on the
>   internet, or making friends with someone who has a Windows 7 computer.
>   If you are lucky your computer manufacturer bundled one with your box.
>   I chose to make one on my Ubuntu machine, using a copy of Windows 7
>   running in VirtualBox, adapting the instructions for making a rescue
>   disk from this [web site](http://windowssecrets.com/insider-tricks/rescue-windows-with-a-bootable-flash-drive/).
>
> The good news is that it does not seem to matter which version of
>   Windows 7 the Repair Disk is obtained from. Since this is a BIOS
>   upgrade it does not even matter whether you use 32-bit or 64-bit
>   versions if your computer is 64-bit.
>
> Once you have a Windows 7 Repair Disk, the rest is easy. You can make
>   it into a bootable USB if you wish, but if your box has a CD drive
>   this is unnecessary. Here are the steps:
>
> 1. Put the downloaded BIOS upgrade .exe on an ordinary USB flash drive.
> 2. Reboot you computer from the Windows 7 Repair Disk, hit the Space bar when prompted.
> 3. Navigate to the command prompt. (Use Recovery Tools->Command Prompt).
> 4. Find the correct drive letter for your USB (on the command line dir a: then b, c, etc. till you find the right one).
> 5. Navigate to it on the command line (type the drive letter with colon).
> 6. Run the file by typing its name (note tab auto-completion works :)).
> 7. From there, just follow the on-screen instructions, and make sure your computer stays powered-on while the upgrade completes.

Perhaps this will [help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100945/how-do-i-update-the-bios-of-a-dell-laptop):

Comment: Using a WIN7/64bits restore disk I get: "the subsystem needed to support the image type is not present"

Comment: Use PE Bart + Windows XP 32bits, I get a weird message (Get System Information ERROR Connect to WMI ERR, hr ...). It seems that I need a full windows OS to get a proper BIOS update.